# Вытянуть столбец с phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Есть код, но он не работает, то есть на странице данные не отображаются, помогите пожалуйста.

```
<?php
$con_str=mysql_connect('domen.ru', 'user', 'password', 'table');
  if(mysql_connect('domen.ru','user')){
        echo "Hello!!!";
    }
  mysql_select_db('passwords',$con_str);
 
$result=mysql_query("SELECT text FROM passwords.table ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 5");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $text=$row['text'];
 
    echo "<p>$text</p>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Возможно проблема в том, что ты используешь mysql_fetch_array, а данные пытаешься брать из ассоциациативного массива. Надо видимо применять mysql_fetch_assoc   . .....   При этом надо понимать что расширение mysql_ устарело лет 10 назад..... Ошибки можно найти - см. в вопросе дубликате

Comment: А phpmyadmin тут при чем?

Comment: @VladimirGonchar не обращайте внимания, новое поколение думает что это БД с данными